# "Good to hear from you"?

Tags: meaning, phrases, greetings

Is it correct to write "Good to hear from you" ?

I have seen it many times but I feel it should be "It feels good to hear from  you" or equivalent.

Comment: It is fine, but you could always add the implied subject and verb and say, "It's good to hear from you." It's still casual, but a native English speaker wouldn't think it odd, as they would with, "It feels good to hear from you."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is correct.

Like in '(I) thank you', the implied words can be omitted.

Answer (score 6):

It's not incorrect, by any means, but it may be less formal than what feels appropriate, which is probably why you are hesitating.  If something doesn't "feel" right, consider your audience and context before focusing on what is or isn't "correct."  It may be that the sentiment itself is not quite what you want for the situation.

Also, if anyone ever said "It feels good to hear from you" to me--in writing or when speaking--I would probably assume that one of us had terminal cancer. (which is to say it's both overly formal and overly intimate at the same time for most situations).  I'd aim more for "It was good hearing from you" or something a tad closer to casual.